# XA5302: Two process may be building this project at once, Xamarin visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, process, android-emulator

I have compiled and run android xamarin project. It has been compiled and run successfully. But showing warning below. If any body guide me so i can save my resources.
[image]

Comment: could it help you ?

Answer (score 6):

Xamarin.Android did not yet produce a warning if Visual Studio invoked one of the Xamarin.Android MSBuild targets while another target was already running in parallel. Xamarin.Android `10.1` now emits a `XA5302` warning in this case so that the Xamarin.Android team can monitor how often this happens and how often it is associated with other build issues.

If you need to suppress this warning, you can add it to the `$(MSBuildWarningsAsMessages)` MSBuild property in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>XA5302</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

you could see [XA5302](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.1#xa5302-warning-when-multiple-msbuild-targets-are-invoked-in-parallel)

Comment: is this warning something we need to worry about? I am starting to see it on my projects as well.

Comment: @Reza you don't need to worry about it

Comment: I’m getting a System Reflection exception while launching xamarin Android. All I see is this. The exception is not healthful. Frustrated

Comment: @Reza Most of the time, we ignored the build warnings while developing application,i think maybe you make some mistakes somewhere,so it throw a exception